# How do I add a Site Information variable and make it multilingual?

Tags: i18n-l10n, forms

So I've used form alter to add in a site information variable (which auto-saves because it's a system_settings_form), but I can't seem to get it to show up as multilingual.

Here is my form alter to add the field:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function omm_form_system_site_information_settings_alter ( &$form, &$form_state ) {
    // Add field in Site Information area of admin configuration.
    $form['site_information']['site_pretitle'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Site Pre-Title'),
        '#description' => t('This will appear above the website name on all pages.'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('site_pretitle', ''),
        '#weight' => '0',
    );
}
```

Edit: I've solved this already, but need 8 hours to post the solution because I'm new.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I managed to solve this after searching through Drupal's code and the Variable module. Turns out if you add a call to `hook_variable_info`, it will add it into the multilingual variables list, and then if you check that off, it makes it translatable like the rest of the Site Information.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_variable_info().
 */
function omm_variable_info($options) {
  // Site configuration, site information
  $variables['site_pretitle'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'title' => t('Site Pre-Title', array(), $options),
    'default' => '',
    'description' => t("This will appear above the website name on all pages.", array(), $options),
    'group' => 'site_information',
  );

  return $variables;
}
```

After adding this, go to `admin/config/regional/i18n/variable` and click on the `Site information` group.  Click the checkmark beside your variable (site_pretitle for mine), and hit `Save configuration`. Once that's done, return to the Site Information area (`admin/config/system/site-information`) and you should see it appear and say `This is a multilingual variable.` in bold.